# How to show progress bar when my list reaches the bottom recyclerview?

Tags: android

I have created stmth like buggy paging library and when I reach the bottom of list I would like to show progress bar before my data will be downloaded. I think that `notifyItemInserted()` will help me bu I don't understand where I have to insert this item. I think that I have to use `notifyItemChanged` also for hiding all data fields and show progress bar at my list item. So, here is my own loading additional data when I reach the end of list:

```
 jobLst.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                if (dy > 0) {
                    val visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.childCount
                    val totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.itemCount
                    val pastVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                    if (loading) {
                        if (visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems >= totalItemCount && !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                 // here I would like to show loader

getJobList(Integer.parseInt(Uri.parse(nextUrl).getQueryParameter("offset")), type, sp.getString("access_token", ""), filterData, true) 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

and I think that I will have to change my item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/message_list_item_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_job_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_company"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_to_notepad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/add_to_notepad"
            android:gravity="end" />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

current progressbar is already used and can't be used for this purpose. So, I will need to add and then remove one item with another view type before and after loading some new data.My main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".jobAGENT.JobsList">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/no_jobs"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_t"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/job_list_t"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

So, what you can advice me?

Comment: I'll say make an ProgressBar at center bottom of the screen and make recylerview above that ProgressBar

Comment: so I have to use relative layout?

Comment: Yes you have to use relative layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I have managed to solve my problem by the easiest way. At main layout where RecyclerView is placed you have to add your ProgressBar which will be below RV and for this purpose you have to use Relative layout. Then you can use scrollListener for recyclerview like this:

```
recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                        loader.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }else{
                        loader.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
            }


        })
```

and when your response will be successful you will hide  your progress bar. Maybe it will help someone else except me :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a special loading `ViewHolder` type for your RecyclerView Adapter and keep the special item at the last one.

The loading `ViewHolder` item layout just include a `ProgressBar`.

**This special item resolution has an advantage is that you can easily use the `RecyclerView` Animation when show or hide loading item.**

```
|=== normal item ====|
|=== normal item ====|
|=== normal item ====|
|=== normal item ====|
|=== normal item ====|
--- insert data here ----
|=== loading item ===|
```

Here is the Adapter demo code, i didn't run the demo but it is enough to show the idea.

```
class ListAdapter(list: List<ItemModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.BaseItemHolder>() {

    companion object {
        private const val VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1
        private const val VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL = 2
    }
    private var mList = list
    private var mShowLoading = false

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseItemHolder {
          when(viewType) {
              VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL -> return NormalViewHolder.create(parent)
              VIEW_TYPE_LOADING -> return LoadingViewHolder.create(parent)
          }
        return BaseItemHolder(parent)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
         // return data list size + loading item size
        return mList.size + if (mShowLoading) { 1 } else { 0 }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseItemHolder, position: Int) {
        if (holder is NormalViewHolder) {
            holder.bind(mList[position])
        } else if (holder is LoadingViewHolder) {
            //do nothing
            //LoadingViewHolder does not need bind data
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        if (position < mList.size) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL
        }
        return VIEW_TYPE_LOADING
    }

    fun hideLoading() {
        mShowLoading = false
        //be careful with the index
        notifyItemRemoved(itemCount)
    }

    fun showLoading() {
        mShowLoading = true
        //be careful with the index
        notifyItemInserted(itemCount - 1)
    }


    open class BaseItemHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    class LoadingViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseItemHolder(itemView) {

        private var mText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title)

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): LoadingViewHolder {
                //R.layout.layout_loading_item just contain a progress bar or something like that
                return LoadingViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_item, parent, false))
            }
        }

        // LoadingViewHolder does not need bind data
        //fun bind() {
        //  
        //}

    }

    class NormalViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseItemHolder(itemView) {

        private var mText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title)

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): NormalViewHolder {
                return NormalViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false))
            }
        }

        fun bind(itemModel: ItemModel) {
            //bind your data with ItemModel data
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but I can't understand these lines: `if (holder is /*normal view holder */) {
            holder.bind(mList[position])
        } else if (holder is /*loadint view holder */) {
            //do something
        }` what I have to do here? and also I have some problems with `onCreateViewHolder()`

Comment: I have update my answer to explain the `bind` process. Because you have two type of item one is `VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL ` another is `VIEW_TYPE_LOADING ` you should handle the `onBindViewHolder` according to the `type`.  Maybe you can search something about the `RecylerView` Adapter with MultipleType.

Comment: you extends BaseItemHolder and where I can find it?

Comment: if I add my adapter will you be able to look through it and say what I have to change please?

Comment: `BaseItemHolder` just a base class you can replace it with `Recycler.ViewHolder` let your `ViewHolder` directly extends `Recycler.ViewHolder`.  You should focus on ViewHolder with multiple type. Just google "RecylcerView Adapter with multiple type" you will get a loooooot of demo. Forget the Loading effect you want to do just go to understand RecyclerView Adapter with multiple type first.  You can do it.

Comment: This is a nice approach

Answer (score 1):

```
Use the below code snippet

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcylv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"/>


    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleX="3"
            android:scaleY="3"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

 And inside activity

 jobLst.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            if (dy > 0) {
                val visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.childCount
                val totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.itemCount
                val pastVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                if (loading) {
                    if (visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems >= totalItemCount && !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
             progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE -> Kotlin
                       or
             progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); -> Java

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I will update my question with main layout, maybe it will help

Answer (score 1):

In your Adapter add this..

```
        @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        if(i==list.size()){
            //show your progress bar
        }
}
```